# kafka client Communication useing log4j

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j2

I want to send log to Kafka broker using log4j.
However, generic messages are well conveyed, and log4j does not.
No errors are displayed.

Please let me know what the problem is!!

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="spring-boot-kafka-log" packages="com.devglan">
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="Kafka" topic="kafkalogger">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message"/>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">IP1:9092,IP2:9092,IP3:9092</Property>
        </Kafka>
        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
        </Async>

        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-7t] %F:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Kafka"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="stdout"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-log4j-appender</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

main.java
@

```
SpringBootApplication
public class Elasticsearch11Application {
    public static final Logger LOG =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(Elasticsearch11Application.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Elasticsearch11Application.class, args);







           Scanner in;
         String topicName = "kafkalogger";
         in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter message(type exit to quit)");
         //Configure the Producer
         Properties configProperties = new Properties();
         configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"IP1:9092,IP2:9092,IP3:9092"); 
         configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
         configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
         org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer producer = new KafkaProducer(configProperties);
         String line = in.nextLine();
         while(!line.equals("exit")) {
         //TODO: Make sure to use the ProducerRecord constructor that does not take parition Id
         ProducerRecord<String, String> rec = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,line);
         producer.send(rec);
         line = in.nextLine();
         }
         in.close();
         producer.close();

        //it's good working code.




        LOG.info("test message:1"); // not working!
        LOG.info("test message:2"); // not working!
```

It does not work well even though I have created an example.

The Kafka broker version is 1.0.0.
The version is well fitted, I checked the operation,

Strangely this can not be done.
Why is this?

Comment: I'm guessing the AsyncAppender doesn't immediately flush messages and is waiting for the app to create more messages. By default, the producer will batch messages, so 2 might not immediately work, but if you tried a loop over 100, it might

Comment: Otherwise, your code is basically the same as https://www.devglan.com/apache-kafka/stream-log4j-logs-to-kafka